# Why is scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh giving the wrong answer?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

Shouldn't the following uses of `eigh` and `eigsh` from the sparse and normal linalg libraries be giving the same answer?

```
from numpy import random
from scipy.linalg import eigh as E1
from scipy.sparse.linalg import eigsh as E2

# Number of eigenvectors to check
kv = 4

# Make a symmetric matrix
N = 20
A = random.random((N,N))
A += A.T
assert( (A==A.T).all() )

L1,V1 = E1(A)
L2,V2 = E2(A,k=kv)

print sorted(L1)[::-1][:kv]
print sorted(L2)[::-1]
```

Some sample values:

```
[20.189135474050769, 3.1309586179883211, 2.6576577451888599, 2.3435647560235355]
[20.18913547405079, 3.1309586179883317, -2.9218877679802597, -3.2962262932479751]

[19.688806193598253, 3.195683848729701, 3.0987244589789058, 2.5648352930907214]
[19.688806193598261, 3.1956838487296961, 3.0987244589789014, -2.7495588013870975]

[20.482117184188727, 3.3175885619590439, 2.8910051228982252, 2.746127351510173]
[20.482117184188716, 3.3175885619590524, 2.891005122898231, 2.7461273515101809]
```

It looks to me like the internal Lancoz routine is only converging sometimes. The maddening thing is that it works for *some* of the values - you can see in the third example that the first four eigenvalues are correct, but that is not the case in the other two examples.

Versions: Python `2.7.3`, numpy `1.6.1`, scipy `0.9.0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to sort the eigenvalues by it's absolute value, the following code will give the same result:

```
print sorted(L1, key=abs)[::-1][:kv]
print sorted(L2, key=abs)[::-1]
```

Comment: If that works, great. But then what is `sorted` sorting by if not the magnitude of the number? Since `eigh` and `eigsh` only take in real symmetric matrices, shouldn't the eigenvalues just be floating point numbers (as opposed to complex numbers)?

Comment: The eigenvalues are just float, but they have sign, some greater than 0, some less than 0.

Comment: You may also use "which=" option in the eigsh function. This allows you get largest or smallest eigenvalues sorted by absolute value or algebraic value

Answer (score -1):

While sorting by absolute values (as suggested by @HYRY) gives the same result for both tests, it still is unsatisfying since the my underlying intent was to get the largest eigenvalues from my matrix. For real symmetric matrices I thought `eigsh` would return the largest eigenvalues. It doesn't, it returns the largest eigenvalues **sorted by magnitude**.

Comment: The behavior is [exactly as documented](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh.html). The `which` parameter controls which eigenvalues are returned, and the default is largest magnitude.